# Escaping single quotes in Jenkins Execute Shell script block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to execute aws-cli command through Jenkins Execute Shell script. But I am facing issue with double quotes and single quotes. Here is the command I want to execute

`aws cloudformation create-stack --template-url templates.url --parameters ParameterKey=TagName,ParameterValue='My Test Job'`

But when I execute my Jenkins job it removes singles quotes and my command becomes

`aws cloudformation create-stack --template-url templates.url --parameters ParameterKey=TagName,ParameterValue=My Test Job`

How can I escape single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

you should share a more complete part of the pipeline so we can understand how are you running that command.
I will asume the simple case that your command is in a sh step in a stage. In this case you must escape the characters .

```
stage('Deploy to Server') {
      steps{
        sh "aws cloudformation create-stack --template-url templates.url --parameters ParameterKey=TagName,ParameterValue=\'My Test Job\'"
      }
}
```

Bear in mind the the log output will not give you the exact command . you should use an echo or a logging function to actually see the command correctly.
Here is a [page](https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4) that helped me a lot in manipulating the strings